# バッジ「スポーツマンシップ」の条件の翻訳を見直したい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 翻訳, バッジ

バッジ「[スポーツマンシップ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship)」の説明文の翻訳で、条件が正確に表現されていないと感じます。

原文:

> Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score

現状の翻訳:

> 質問への 100 件の回答にプラス票を投じていて、あなたの回答のスコアがポジティブになっている

「where」以下が「question」に掛かっている構造が翻訳からは失われています。現在の翻訳でも考えれば解ることかも知れませんが、もう少し自然に理解可能な文が良いと思います。

Comment: 新しい翻訳の案はありますか？　この string はおそらく https://ja.traducir.win/strings/7256 なので書き換えはすぐできそうです。

Comment: [こちら MSE の投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108883/314875)を読み、「スポーツマンシップ」という名前を考慮するとこのような意味合いになるかしらという翻訳案がうかびましたので回答欄に載せておきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

無事サイトへ反映されました。今後もしも変更が必要になった場合には、どうぞお声がけくださいませ。

[image: スポーツマンシップ]

Answer (score 3):

もしよろしければ、こちらを編集、改善してお使いくださいませ  。

---

原文:

> Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score

翻訳案:

> あなたが投稿した回答のスコアが 1 以上であり、その質問に対する別のユーザーからの回答へプラス票を投じた回数が 100 を超えた

Comment: 本題とは違いますが「positive score」を「スコアが 1 以上」とするのは日本語話者にとって解り易くてよいですね。機会が有れば他の箇所もこの訳にしていくと良いかも知れません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！こちらで一旦反映いたします